# calculate 2 date.now gives NaN, even with parseInt

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript, and I need to calculate the difference between 2 timestamps (in seconds). one is when the user clicks on the first card, the other one is when he clicks on the last one.

my code:

```
var startTime = Date.now();
var endTime = Date.now();
var currentResult = ((endTime - startTime)/1000);
```

this gives NaN in the console, but I can see the long numbers if I do:

```
console.log(startTime);
console.log(endTime);
```

even when I use:

```
var startMillsecond = parseInt(startTime, 10);
var endMillsecond = parseInt(endTime, 10);
```

and then calculate:

```
currentResult = ((endMillsecond - startMillsecond)/1000);
```

it gives NaN as well. What am I doing wrong? I need to use only javascript..
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Comment: Don't see how you can possibly get NaN from what is shown. Provide a [mcve] that reproduces it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.now()` returns a floating point number representing a number of miliseconds. Subtracting of from the other then dividing by 1000 gives a number of seconds. So this works:

```js
var startTime = Date.now();
setTimeout(function() {
  var endTime = Date.now();
  var currentResult = ((endTime - startTime) / 1000);
  console.log(currentResult)
}, 3125);
```

IOW, you're doing something else than you posted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand where is the mistake. the startTime was not declared outside the function, so when I tried to do the difference it gave a mistake (the function runs every time the user clicks on a card). Thank you